# understand about what decltype returns in c++

Tags: c++

I'm very confused with decltype.

In the wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics), there is an example.

```cpp
const int&& foo();
const int bar();
int i;
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(foo()) x1; // type is const int&&
decltype(bar()) x2; // type is int
decltype(i) x3; // type is int
decltype(a->x) x4; // type is double
decltype((a->x)) x5; // type is const double&
```

But, I don't understand at all about it.

1. `decltype(bar()) x2; // type is int`

I think type should be `const int` because `bar()` returns `const int` and `decltype(foo())` returns `const int&&`. But, why is it just an `int`?

2. `decltype((a->x)) x5; // type is const double&`

As wiki said,

> The reason for the difference between the latter two invocations of decltype is that the parenthesized expression (a->x) is neither an id-expression nor a member access expression, and therefore does not denote a named object.[13] Because the expression is an lvalue, its deduced type is "reference to the type of the expression", or const double&

wiki said that the expression `(a->x)` is an lvalue. But, AFAIK, lvalue is something that points to a specific memory location. Namely, it has its name or identifier. I think `a->x` does got its name, but `(a->x)` dosen't. Why it is a lvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), we can classify that:

1. return type of `const int&& foo();` is an xvalue.
2. return type of `const int bar();` is a prvalue.

Searching for this brought me to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lval) which states:

> non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types

So its understood that return type of `bar()` is an `int` since its not a class type.

As to you second query:

> Why it is a lvalue?

Because it has been mentioned in the standard as such. [cppreference note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression

You can think of `(a->x)` as being the lhs of an assignment, and thus `decltype((a->x))` returns a reference `const int&`.

Comment: The Example's bar() is not from the linked standard. A W~ editor has added these 2 lines. And put the explanation in hidden html, revealable by clicking on "edit".